# Arithmetic question regarding inside of square root

Tags: arithmetic

Okay so say I have $ (2\cos(x)^{2})^{1/2} $

can anyone show me the proof that $ (2)^{1/2} \cos(x) $ is = to the first one?

http://www.rapidtables.com/math/number/exponent.htm

I was looking at this website and could not find anything relating to different base different exponent.

Comment: I have attempted to format your question into something readable. I think the problem goes away if you interpret $\cos(x)^2$ as $(\cos x)^2$.

Comment: Hey what is the difference between $ cos(x)^(2) $ and $(cosx)^(2)$ ???

Comment: Wolfram gives me the same result for both  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(cosx%5E(2))  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(cosx)%5E(2)     but where it says "input" in wolfram, that's what I intended it to look like in my post. Anyways do you have an answer to my question??

Comment: The difference is that $\cos(x)^2$ is ambiguous. It could be interpreted as $\cos(x^2)$. But, anyway, do you understand why $(2(\cos x)^2)^{1/2}=2^{1/2}\cos x$?

Comment: I see, well I intended it to be written the second way you wrote it Gerry, $(cosx)^(2)$... but no, I don't understand why. I've been looking on the internet and I can't find any rules or proofs for exponents of different bases with same powers..

Comment: The only rules you need are $(ab)^c=a^cb^c$ and $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$. The other thing you need is some help with formatting mathematics on this site so that you don't get $a^(b)$ when you want $a^{(b)}$, and the help menu may get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Your 'equation' $$\sqrt{2(\cos x)^2} = \sqrt{2}\cos x$$ is **wrong**. Take e.g. $x=\pi,\;$ then the LHS is $\sqrt{2}$ but the RHS evaluates to  $-\sqrt{2}.$ 
Generally you have $\sqrt{a^2}=|a|\;$ for real $a.$

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. So would making the RHS  $\sqrt{2}\ |cosx|$ make the equation true??